# How to execute this type of oracle store procedure if i want to see the last_name whose employee_id=iemp_id

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package hr.emp_pkg as
TYPE ref_cursor is REF CURSOR;
PROCEDURE sel ( o_res OUT ref_cursor, i_emp_id IN hr.employees.employee_id%TYPE);
end emp_pkg;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY hr.emp_pkg as

 PROCEDURE sel ( o_res OUT ref_cursor, i_emp_id IN hr.employees.employee_id%TYPE
    )
  IS
BEGIN
      OPEN o_res FOR
      SELECT DISTINCT
        employee_id,
        last_name,
        first_name,
        salary
     FROM hr.employees
     WHERE employee_id = i_emp_id;
END;

end emp_pkg;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way in SQL*Plus.

```
SQL> variable c refcursor

SQL> exec hr.emp_pkg.sel(:c, 100);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print :c

EMPLOYEE_ID LAST_NAME                 FIRST_NAME               SALARY
----------- ------------------------- -------------------- ----------
        100 King                      Steven                    24000
```